# I can't add new security inbound rules in microsoft azure

Tags: azure, inbound-security-rule

My rules parameter are correcte, here a screen shot
when i clic "ok" i have the message error

`Notifications
Dismiss:InformationalCompletedAll
Failed to create security rule
Failed to create security rule 'FTP_Port_21'. Error: error`

with no more detail on error message i can't do any things on my side

screen shot of azure screen :

[inbound rules :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rbf9P.jpg)

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ln19y.jpg)

when i use Azure NSG web page to view my active rules configuartion, i have an error message see in the new screenshot :
[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bMjko.jpg)

I Try to delete the NSG but I have an error :

`Échec de la suppression du groupe de sécurité réseau
Échec de la suppression du groupe de sécurité réseau 'advertisingpreprod-nsg'. Erreur : error`

Comment: New plan, remove the NSG association from the network card, delete the NSG, create a new NSG, add rules, add it to network card. Looks like your current NSG is in limbo.

Comment: I will try it tomorow if i don-t have other choice. I wait for other solution !!!

Comment: I try to delete the NSG axxoiation from network card but it don(t work. I have this message : Failed to delete network security group
Failed to delete network security group 'advertisingpreprod-nsg'. Error: error

Answer (score 0):

Try refreshing the browser and check once changing the priority of port no may solve your issue. See if this helps.
[created inbound rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AwuJg.png) [port added successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hrbv1.png)
Suggest you to refer troubleshooting ports in [Azure NSG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-nsg-troubleshoot-portal).

Comment: i update my question with the response of your web page help